# What are the advantages/disadvantages of Apache VHOSTS over Docker Instances?

Tags: docker

Just wondering what the general opinion was on running multiple websites on one server. Would you rather use one apache install and seperate them with vhosts, or run each site seperately in its own apache docker process?

If someone could throw some advantages/disadvantages that would really help me out.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the two scenarios?

Comment: No, I don't. Maybe you could help me understand it.

Comment: Docker provides isolation, which roughly translates to that each website has its own physical machine.  VHOSTS tell Apache to respond to multiple different names with each their set of web files.   Given your current level of knowledge I would start with VHOSTS.